# Is it possible to use app script with Google Sheets to create a bar graph with unique colors for each bar?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, bar-chart

Manually creating a bar graph with unique colors for each bar is essentially impossible at this point due to [buggy behavior](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/132124/unable-to-change-google-sheets-data-point-format-without-changing-other-data-poi) with Google's graph editor. I want to programmatically modify an existing graph using app script so that I can arbitrarily assign colors to each bar. I have so far tried two approaches shown below. Both fail and seemingly in the same way-- they pick out only the first color in the array (for the case of the first attempt) or the first key-value pair in the second. Am I doing something syntactically wrong here or is what I am attempting even possible with app script?

```
function changeColors() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.modify()
  .setOption('colors', ['red', 'blue','green', 'pink','purple', 'black', 'black'])
  .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}

function changeColors() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.modify()
  // Set the series options.
  .setOption("series", {
    0: {
    color: 'black',    
    },
    1: {
    color: 'red'
    }
  })
  .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}
```

Comment: It's possible - from what I remember you need to add separate data sets for the data to show up on the chart in different colors.

Answer (score 0):

As I answered to the question you linked, there is no bug for changing bar colors from the Sheets UI.

**If you wish to change the colors with Apps Script**, the method you are using

`.setOption('colors', ['red', 'blue','green', 'pink','purple', 'black', 'black'])`

is correct, you just have to make sure that your chart has at least as many ranges as colors specified.

When you build your chart, you have to define every bar as a separate range. Something like:

```
function myChart()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var firstRange = sheet.getRange("first bar");
  var secondRange = sheet.getRange("second bar");
  ...
  var seventhRange = sheet.getRange("seventh bar");

  var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
    .addRange(firstRange)
    .addRange(secondRange)
    ...
    .addRange(seventhRange)
    .setOption('colors', ['red', 'blue','green', 'pink','purple', 'black', 'black'])
    .setPosition(1, 1, 0, 0);

  var chart = chartBuilder.build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);  
}
```

BTW, if you do not specify the colors, the chartbuilder will by default plot each range in a different color, anyway.